# Addaing a value to an existing key in associative array

Tags: php, validation, associative-array

So I'm trying to add a value to an existing key in an associative array. Key 'message' is for displaying different errors based on validation.

```
$formStatus = [
        'success' => false, 
        'message' => "Phone number validation failed"
    ];
```

I want to add another message later, on the same key, if lets say email validation fails. Is this even possible ?

Comment: `$formStatus['message'] = 'Your Custom Message';` did you tried? or just asking ?

Comment: https://onecompiler.com/php/3xupy7rca Working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can also use **array_replace()** function

$formStatus = [
        'success' => false, 
        'message' => "Phone number validation failed"
        ];
        print_r($formStatus); //printing array for checking

        $formStatus = array_replace($formStatus, array("message" => "Email validation failed"));

        print_r($formStatus); //printing array for checking
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change $formStatus like this:

```
        $formStatus = [
        'success' => false,
        'validation' => [
            'phone_message' => 'Phone number validation failed',
            'email_message' => 'Email validation failed',
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: Also very useful, but for my case atomankion solution is more suitable. Thank you !